# Invision + Wordpress integration

Tags: scripts, customization

I'm trying to integrate Invision Power Board into our website, Wordpress by using IPB Website Integration (IPBWI).

I have used the script sometime before on a static website, but I'm having trouble with the integration in Wordpress.

The script is actually working as intended in Wordpress, but I am getting a lot of warning-messages throughout the site, like this:

```
Strict Standards: call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, non-static method RCCWP_Query::FilterCustomPostsFields() should not be called statically in [path]\wp-includes\plugin.php on line 220
Strict Standards: call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, non-static method RCCWP_Query::FilterCustomPostsJoin() should not be called statically in [path]\wp-includes\plugin.php on line 220
Strict Standards: call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, non-static method RCCWP_Query::FilterCustomPostsOrderby() should not be called statically in [path]\wp-includes\plugin.php on line 220
Strict Standards: call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, non-static method RCCWP_Query::FilterCustomPostsFields() should not be called statically in [path]\wp-includes\plugin.php on line 220
```

It is mainly where I have custom queries I get these warnings

This might be beyond the scope of support witch this board gives, but hopefulle someone might know some solutions.

Comment: Got help from the application author, and have disabled PHP error-reporting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the error you see is given by PHP and is giving you a hint that the code you use has not been programmed carefully. It is violating strict standards, in you case, a function is called in a way it should not. That's basically all.

I assume on the server you just have installed the integration, there is some other PHP configuration. So previously on some other configuration there was not such error reporting given.

Please contact the author(s) of the wordpress IPB integration and report the error you are getting back to them. If they have questions back, please try the best you can to answer their questions. This will help them to improve the software.

If you are a coder your own, you can as well fix the problem on your end and report the problem with the solution back to project.

Comment: Okey, I will try to look into it a bit more. Either way, hopefully I will find a solution for it.. Thanks for your reply

Comment: Do you know of any other Wordpress/Invision-integration scripts? I have only found IPBWI, witch is currently actively developed.

Comment: @Martin: No, I don't know any other. If it's actively developed, work together with the developers. This will help you most.